# Run routing as an event

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have a frontend javascript application built with require.js and backbone.js. Most parts of the application use the standard/recommended way of building application, including routing by using the Backbone Router object.

Now I want to add some more visual changes in one part of the application. Instead of clicking a link and the router render another view, I want some visual changes before that happens. Like GUI-effects happening when clicking the link, then when that effect is complete, the new view should render like before.

I guess one possible way to do this is by hooking a click event to the given link, cancel normal propagation (canceling the route catching in the backbone object), perform the visual stuff, and then manually call the router or render the view directly. Then I would need to have access to the router object from the view (to call the action method that normally catch the click), or I would need to render the view from within the click event added to the link, causing the render code to be duplicated (in the event function and in the view).

Is there a good and tidy way to do something like this, without making ugly spaghetti-code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to catch all clicks on every link, and then do what you want :

```
$(document).on('click', 'a:not([data-bypass])', function (evt) {

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var protocol = this.protocol + '//';

    if (href.slice(protocol.length) !== protocol) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var rootLength = Backbone.history.root.length - ((Backbone.history.root.substring(Backbone.history.root.length - 1) === '/') ? 1 : 0);

        // Here before calling the history.navigate that trigger your router 
        // routes, do your visual effects

        Backbone.history.navigate(href.slice(rootLength), {
            trigger: true
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I have not used history.navigate before. It solved my case. A little strange that it is not included in the Backbone documentation..